# What are good ways of determining at runtime how much memory is allowed/available to a windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c++, memory-management, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

Working in MSVS 2015, it's a c++ windows phone 8.1 project.

I've jury-rigged a method that works--I do something like a binary search by allocating and freeing memory; if the allocation works, I increase the size, if it doesn't I decrease it, etc.  However, repeated allocation and deallocation seems clunky, inelegant, and likely to cause problems whose specifics I don't actually know yet, call it intuition.

For instance, when testing on the 512 MB phone emulator, I end up finding that I actually have only in the neighborhood of 160 MB for my app to utilize.  That's fine and all, but I wouldn't have known what the actual amount of memory I could allocate was without testing.

What options are available to me to find that number (with the available apis)?

Comment: Have you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I haven't yet!  That's certainly quite relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [App memory limits for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681682%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can found some info about memory limit for windows app.

[image]

And as you can see some [workaround about memory statistics](http://www.codeguru.com/win_mobile/phone_apps/how-to-work-with-the-memory-limits-of-windows-phone-apps.htm) you can use some API as below in C#

```
private void buttonGetMemoryMetrics_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            long totalBytes = DeviceStatus.DeviceTotalMemory;
            long usageLimit = DeviceStatus.ApplicationMemoryUsageLimit;
            long currentUsage = DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage;
            ulong commitLimit = MemoryManager.ProcessCommittedLimit;
            ulong currentCommit = MemoryManager.ProcessCommittedBytes;
 
            long workingsetLimit = 0;
            object temp;
            if(DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("ApplicationWorkingSetLimit", out temp))
                workingsetLimit = (long)temp;
 
 
            textBlockApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage.Text = currentUsage.ToString();
            textBlockApplicationMemoryUsageLimit.Text = usageLimit.ToString();
            textBlockApplicationWorkingSetLimit.Text = workingsetLimit.ToString();
            textBlockBytesCommitLimit.Text = commitLimit.ToString();
            textBlockBytesCommitted.Text = currentCommit.ToString();
            textBlockDeviceTotalMemory.Text = totalBytes.ToString();
            
        }
```

For C++ usage you can see [MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsageLimit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.memorymanager.appmemoryusagelimit.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) . You can found some useful informations about APIs in [MemoryManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.memorymanager.aspx) section.